# zookeeper: how to delete id from ACL?

Tags: authentication, authorization, apache-zookeeper, znodes

I've added some id's to certain znode by using addauth and setAcl digest. For example when I do getAcl /app, I get `'user1, ' hashvalue :crdwa`. How to delete this record from ACL list?